# Proving a Limit Using the Binomial Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The definition that I am using by the way is letting $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary, show that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$,  such that $n\ge N$ implies $|n^{1/n}-1|<\epsilon$.

Prove form this definition of the limit of a sequence :
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$, also using the facts that $n^{1/n}=1+k_n$.

And then use the Binomial Theorem to prove that $n \ge 1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}k_n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

As 
$$
n^{1/n}=1+k_n,
$$
then the binomial expansion of $(1+k_n)^n$ provides
$$
n=(1+k_n)^n=1+nk_n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}k_n^2+\cdots \ge \frac{n(n-1)}{2}k_n^2,
$$
and thus
$$
n\ge \frac{n(n-1)}{2}k_n^2,
$$
or
$$\frac{2}{n-1}\ge k_n^2, \quad\text{for}\,\,n\ge 2.
$$
Finally
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n-1}}\ge k_n\ge 0, \quad\text{for}\,\,n\ge 2,
$$
which implies that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}k_n=0,
$$
and thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1.
$$